# normalizing String with adding appropriate spacing

Tags: java, string-comparison, string-matching

probably a very broad question for stackoverflow but here it goes,

I'm trying to normalize words within sentence, for example:

**INPUT:**

- I developGeographicallydispersed teams through good ASDWEQ.

**OUTPUT**
(Notice the spaces between **develop Geographically dispersed**)

- I develop Geographically dispersed teams through good ASDWEQ.

since using external API is out of option ( e.g. using **google API**).
I require to design our in house `Java API`

the obvious and naive solution would be something like this:

```
for all word in sentence do:
   if word is in dictionary then ignore
   else:
        if word is reduce-able to a set of dictionary keywords then split
        else ignore

od;
```

So before I start with such approach, my question is that if there is a better way of doing it? for example some an **OPEN SOURCE library**, or even different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) and [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) ? It helps to create a scanner and define your patterns for text processing, you should find a trick to map your parser to an existing dictionary in your case.

Comment: aren't those just tokenzier used for compilers? this case is very simple to split the text. just spilit by spaces